# QListView Complexe Delegate editor focus to parent

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a QListView where each rows are represented has a complex widget.

I want to have a QLabel and a QTableView representing some data.

All good so far.

The problem is that when i click on the QTableView (which i disabled the focus policy), it doesn't select the row of the QListView.

But it's working when i click on the QLabel (which is also disabled focus policy)

Is there anything i do wrong ? My change_line method does get called when clicking on the "This is line" label but not on the table bellow it :(

I've tried to play with the FocusPolicy and the setFocusProxy in the editor, but so far can't make it work.

Thanks for the help

```py
import sys
from typing import Any, Dict

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractListModel, QModelIndex, Qt, QAbstractTableModel, QSize
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaMetaData
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QListView, QWidget, QStyledItemDelegate, \
    QTableView, QHeaderView, QAbstractScrollArea, QLabel


class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._data_list = []

    @property
    def data_list(self):
        return self._data_list

    @data_list.setter
    def data_list(self, data_list):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self._data_list = data_list
        self.endResetModel()

    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: QMediaMetaData.Orientation, role: int = ...) -> Any:
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if section == 0:
                return "header"

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = ...) -> Any:
        if index.column() == 0:
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return self.data_list[index.row()]

    def rowCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ..., *args, **kwargs) -> int:
        return len(self.data_list)

    def columnCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ..., *args, **kwargs) -> int:
        return 1


class ListModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex(), *args, **kwargs) -> int:
        return 2

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = Qt.DisplayRole) -> Any:
        if index.row() == 0:
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return ["Hello", "World!"]
        elif index.row() == 1:
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return ["One", "Two", "Three!"]

class ItemEditor(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.line_label = QLabel("This is a line", self)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.line_label)
        self.table_view = QTableView(self)
        self.table_view.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.table_view.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.table_view.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
        self.table_view.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.table_view.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.table_view)


class StyledItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(StyledItemDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self.editors: Dict[int, QTableView] = {}

    def sizeHint(self, option: 'QStyleOptionViewItem', index: QModelIndex) -> QSize:
        if index.row() in self.editors.keys():
            return QSize(min(self.parent().width(), self.editors[index.row()].sizeHint().width()),
                         self.editors[index.row()].sizeHint().height())
        else:
            return super(StyledItemDelegate, self).sizeHint(option, index)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = ItemEditor(parent)
        editor.setFocusProxy(parent)

        editor.table_view.setModel(TableModel())
        editor.table_view.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)

        header = editor.table_view.horizontalHeader()
        header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.Stretch)

        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor: QTableView, index):
        editor.table_view.model().data_list = index.data()
        self.editors[index.row()] = editor

def change_line(index: QModelIndex):
    # FIXME Only working when clicking on the "editor" widget or the QLabel, not on the Table
    print(f"Changing to line {index.row()}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    main_window = QMainWindow()

    centralwidget = QWidget(main_window)
    verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(centralwidget)
    listView = QListView(centralwidget)
    listView.clicked.connect(change_line)

    verticalLayout.addWidget(listView)

    main_window.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)

    listModel = ListModel()
    listView.setModel(listModel)

    delegate = StyledItemDelegate(listView)
    listView.setItemDelegate(delegate)

    for i in range(listModel.rowCount()):
        index = listModel.index(i, 0)
        listView.openPersistentEditor(index)

    main_window.resize(600,400)
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Is the table never going to accept any mouse event?

Comment: Indeed, the table should just allow to click to select the parent row, nothing else. This is just a "read only" view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no mouse interaction is required, a possibility is to make the table "transparent" to mouse events:

```
    self.table_view.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)
```

Note that by default the editor doesn't change the size hint of the cell but the other way around, so you should emit [`sizeHintChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#sizeHintChanged) when creating the editor, and you should add the editor to the dictionary in `createEditor`, not in `setEditorData`.

```
    self.editors[index.row()] = editor
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: self.sizeHintChanged.emit(index))

    return editor
```

Comment: Hey thanks ! This is working great :) Nice catch on the editor sizeHintChanged ! I'll change that in my code !